# Trying to access lighttpd sever in other pc

Tags: lighttpd

So, I've this situation:

I have recently installed Lighttpd in ubuntu (In VM Ware), I am trying to bind the IP to the Lighttpd server and access that IP address (from a browser) in my other system (within different network), I'm trying this for testing my website before sending it to the actual server.

Thank you.

Comment: You don't assign IPs to services, you assign them to the system. Afterwards you can bind a service to them.

Comment: This question could benefit from having an actual question. What isn't working? What have you tried? What do you need help with?